# Ionic3 Side-menu are show but visible inner content?

Tags: ionic3

I have implemented the simple side-menu in our app I have properly implemented the code of side but side-menu are the show but inner content are not visible tell me anyone what ’s wrong in my code?

```html
<ion-header>
  <ion-navbar>
    <button ion-button [menuToggle]="activeMenu">
      <ion-icon name="menu"></ion-icon>
    </button>
    <ion-title>
       Menu
    </ion-title>
  </ion-navbar>
</ion-header>


<ion-menu [content]="mycontent">
  <ion-content>
    <ion-list>
      <p>some menu content, could be list items</p>
       <ion-item menuClose detail-none>Close Menu</ion-item>
    </ion-list>
  </ion-content>
</ion-menu>

<ion-nav #mycontent [root]="rootPage"></ion-nav>
```

Comment: I tried your code [here in stackblitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/stackoverflow-menu) and it is fine.

Comment: yes sir..actually mistake at my side acctually i put the code of sidemenu in wrong seperate ts file.but tell me 1 thing sir why code is not working if i put the code inside the seperate ts file ?